# Analyze a trend for a technology

Tags: support, trends

I need to know if a technology I'd like to use is still spread and used by people. 
Is there a dedicated page in Stack Overflow where I can see by a chart the popularity trend of that technology over time?

For example: Zend Framework. When was it introduced? When was it popular? And now?

Comment: Google e.g. `framework popularity charts`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is such a page: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends

> See how technologies have trended over time based on use of their tags since 2008, when Stack Overflow was founded. Enter up to 15 tags to compare growth and decline.

For example, the [`zend-framework` and `zend-framework2` trend graph](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=zend-framework%2Czend-framework2) shows that that framework is in decline in popularity since 2011; the newer version notwithstanding:

[image: Trend graph for the zend-framework and zend-framework2 tags, showing a gradual decline since 2011]

This shows how often these tags were *used on Stack Overflow*; this does not tell you when the technology was developed, or if it is still actively maintained. But the number of questions asked for a given tag can be seen as a strong indicator of popularity.

Comment: I'm not so sure this is reflective of "popularity" as this is based on the number of questions that have the tag. For older platforms, I'd argue a big contributor to fewer new posts is that older posts have already covered a lot of the common ground. For a new platform there is much more ground to cover.

Comment: @Avner: most topics are complex and varied enough that there is still room for new questions. For still-popular topics, you do get a certain number of questions that may cover already-answered problems, which need to be closed as duplicates, they don't disappear. Next, popular platforms usually are still actively developed and so not static, fuelling more questions. Compare the above graph with the [two most prevalent Python web frameworks, Django and Flask](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=flask%2Cdjango) to see that they draw a steady stream of questions still.

Comment: Martijn Thanks for your comment. My counterpoint is something like [jquery](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=jquery) Looking at the trend suggests popularity is greatly waning. Yet [SO Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#most-popular-technologies) has it as the most popular web framework. My point is you can't always rely on the trend as the indicator.

Comment: @Avner: but it *is* waning, because a lot of front-end dev is [switching to frameworks like angular and react](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=jquery%2Creactjs%2Cangular). The survey also [names rust as most loved](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted), but that just reflects what the respondents maybe *want* to do, not [what they actually ask questions about](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=rust%2Cpython%2Ctypescript%2Ckotlin).

Comment: Martijn, disagree that is what people _want_ to use, the blurb below says: "jQuery is the most broadly used of these web frameworks". Sure I would agree that the trend is waning, but its still the most widely used framework. Just looking at the trend would misinform its current popularity.

Comment: @Avner: but this question is *about trends*. jQuery's popularity is waning, that's the trend. It may still be the most popular, but it won't be in the future, that's what the trend is telling you, and why people want to see trends, not just absolute popularity numbers.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know when a technology was developed, or how popular it is in general, there's nowhere on this network to find that information. Wikipedia will tell you for most technologies when they were introduced, but popularity is hard to nail down.

If you want to check how popular a technology is *on Stack Overflow*, then you can use the [Stack Overflow Trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=zend-framework) tool.

1. Give it a moment to load.
2. Delete the default tags.
3. Type in the tag of the language or technology you're interested in.